# Slim framework merge array to view data

Tags: php, slim

I have a Slim application, in the main Middleware I add some generic data to the model

**middleware "call" method code**

```
$app->view->set("auths",["user","poweruser"]);
```

In a controller method I want to push a value to the "auths" array of the view model, is there any way to access it in a faster way than this?:

**controller method code**

```
$data=$app->view->get("auths");
$data[]="newauth";
$app->view->set("auths",$data);
```

Answer (score 2):

### In short

No, you can't, but you could define your own view subclass if you want to wrap this functionality nicely.

### Native Slim

I just checked out Slim's source code (which is really, really, .. Slim), and you are using its View object which wraps a Set object. Neither supplies this functionality, since the internal array isn't exposed and the all() and getData() methods don't return the internal array by reference, so this **won't** work:

```
$view->all()['auths'][] = 'newauth';
```

You can reach what you want directly with the following nasty one-liner:

```
$view->set('auths', array_merge($view->get('auths'), ['newauth']));
```

### Roll your own View subclass

Much better would be to define your own custom view that makes this possible!

1. Define a custom view class

   ```
   class CustomView extends \Slim\View
   {
       public function pushProperty($key, $value)
       {
           $array = $this->get($key);
           $array[] = $value;
           $this->set($key, $array);
       }
   }
   ```

   **Note:** this method blindly assumes that the current value is an array. You will want to add some checks!
2. Assign it as the default view object in your Slim app when you create it.

   ```
   $app = new Slim\Slim(array('view' => new CustomView()));
   ```
3. And start using it :)

   ```
   $app->view->set("auths",["user","poweruser"]);
   $app->view->pushProperty('auths','newauth'); // this will now work. Yay :)
   ```